# App screenshots not loading in

Tags: ios, submit

so I am currently in the process of submitting my IOS app for review. Whenever I go to drag a screenshot in literally nothing happens. I have the dimensions right so I am not getting an error anymore. I drag it in and the screenshot never pops up.

Does anyone have this problem?

thanks.

Comment: are you using Safari?

Comment: I have tried it on both safari and google chrome and the same thing keeps happening. I changed the image size in photo shop and everything

Comment: Try to refresh the iTunes Connect or logout and login again

Comment: Make sure your images don't have any transparency. Try with some JPG.

Comment: You might need to leave it some time - Apple have an issue with sometimes things not working correctly!

Comment: Alright. I tried all of these things and nothing worked. I will leave it for a day or two and see if that works. Thanks guys